# URL routing from database

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have database table in this structure:

```
id  title description URL  
1   abc   abc desc    abc  
2   xyz   xyz desc    xyz-123  
3   tit   Description web-description  
...
```

I need to generate web pages from my database table such as:
    domain.com/abc
    domain.com/xyz-123
    domain.com/web-description

I dont´t know where and how to set rewrite rule to take it from my database table. I don´t want to use robust framework such as Zend, I want only sample code to solve this problem. Please, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with database. You can take those from array of text file. The result is the same - you will have to implement router yourself.

Comment: ok but I don´t know how to implement router - this is a question...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from php and .htaccess file.

1. Make text file name with .htaccess and save on your document root.
2. Put following content into .htaccess file.
3. Your php file name should be index.php

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1

Thats all.

When you execute url another url has executed.

Ex:

`domain.com/xyz-123` will execute `domain.com/index.php?id=xyz-131`
`domain.com/web-description` will execute `domain.com/index.php?id=web-description`

Note: Apache rewite module should be enabled

Comment: Thanks, but i want have domain.com/xyz-123, not domain.com/index.php?id=xyz-123

Comment: Yes You can execute domain.com/xyz-123, it's works and URL displayed as domain.com/xyz-123

But you shouldn't create a directory as xyz-123 under your document root. URL displays as domain.com/xyz-123 and executes as domain.com/index.php?id=xyz-123 or any patern according to your script

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://www.kratedesign.com/blog/2010/03/29/php-router-and-clean-urls/) tutorial, but you should really edit your question title to remove irrelevant "database" part from it.